# Private Windows 10 Enterprise Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-10

Has anyone out there figured out how to set up private windows stores for easier deployment so that we don't have to do power shell scripts or remote debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a business store for Windows 10 integrated in the public store. You will be able to use it as a business customer in the future.

Right now it's not available yet. See screenshot.

[image]